# How to get WTForms to require entry into a RadioButton field?

Tags: python, flask-wtforms

I'm creating a web form using Flask and Flask-WTF. The form is dynamic, with the fields determined by the database. Some questions in the database specify a radio button field, while others specify a single word.

I need to require that the radio button fields have a selection. Using `wtforms.validators.DataRequired` works perfectly for the string fields, but not the radio fields.

```
...
    if question.category == 'word':
        field = StringField(question.question, validators=[DataRequired()])
    elif question.category == 'likert':
        choices = [('1', 'Strongly Agree'), ('2', ...
        field = RadioField(question.question, choices=choices,
                           validators=[DataRequired()])
    setattr(FlaskForm, str(question.id), field)
stator(FlaskForm, 'submit', SubmitField('Submit))
form = FlaskForm()
....
```

Leaving any string field blank results in an error message when submitted. But nothing happens if a radio field is left without a selection.

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still don't know why `DataRequired` (and `InputRequired`) don't properly work with radio fields, but here's how I solved it.

I subclassed `FlaskForm` as follows:

```
class SurveyForm(FlaskForm):
    class Meta:
        def render_field(self, field, render_kw):
            render_kw.setdefault('required', True)
            return super().render_field(field, render_kw)
```

Using adding the dynamic fields to an instance of this subclass then made even the radio fields require an input.